# Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /home/stevenst/public_html/upgrade/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600

Tags: xml, fatal-error, varien, ce-1.4.2.0

I have created a clone of my original site in a subdomain.  Now this is the error I keep getting.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in
>   /home/stevenst/public_html/upgrade/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 600

This is from the system log:

> 2015-05-13T13:52:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string()
>   [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 135: parser error : Premature end of data in tag config
>   line 28  in
>   /home/stevenst/public_html/upgrade/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510 2015-05-13T13:52:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:   in /home/stevenst/public_html/upgrade/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php
>   on line 510 2015-05-13T13:52:57+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: ^  in
>   /home/stevenst/public_html/upgrade/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on
>   line 510

Comment: Did you make a typo in local.xml or perhaps not wrap a value inside cdata section? Common mistake is a password with &, < or >. Or people don't close the cdata correctly when editing.

Comment: please post your local.xml from app>etc

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  It was a permissions error or a malformed xml file.  I just ran an rsync -p on with my production site and it corrected whatever permissions or xml was wrong.  Thank you all for the advice.